# (emacs:28245): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: IA__g_object_notify: object class `GtkMenuItem' has no property named `label'

Tags: warning

working on Red Hat Gnome 2.16.0 (pretty old, I guess).
Whenever I launch emacs 24.4.1, i keep getting these warnings
popping on the terminal I launched it from.

Can anybody either point me to a possible cause of the issue,
or suggest how to turn these warnings off?

They tend to clog my terminal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to commends on Emacs bug#16522: (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2014-01/msg01157.html), this is a bug when using Emacs with GTK version earlier than 2.16.

I've personally seen this on RHEL 5 (GTK 2.10.4), but not on RHEL 6 (GTK 2.24.23).

Comment: Thanks -- do you know how to check the GTK version on my machine?

Comment: @Mike It will depend on the platform. On RHEL/CentOS, `rpm -q gtk2` gives the version installed. Debian/Ubuntu should be `aptitude show gtk+2.0` (I don't have access to a system, so this is from memory).

Comment: in my version it is `rpm -q gtk2` indeed, and it returns `gtk2-2.10.4-21.el5_7.7` as you predicted.